Ffmpeg capturing webcam and audio: audio stops playing towards the end of the video
This is the command:
ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -i /dev/video0 test.mp4
Playing the recording during the last 5 seconds there is no audio.
It's always 5 seconds, regardless the length of the video
So now i need the audio to perfectly match the video, what should i do?
